# unable to connect to email host to read emails on linux environment

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am not able to connect to email host through `javax.mail` in `linux` environment. Everything is working fine in `windows OS` but on deploying `jar` to linux I am getting following exception:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Invalid login or password
        at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:207)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
        at com.bric.service.MailReceiverService.receiveAndStoreMail(MailReceiverService.java:98)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Code I am using to read emails is :

```
try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
            properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
            Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            
            Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
            store.connect(host, user_, password_);
            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
                Message message = messages[i];
                if(message.getSubject().startsWith("Pacific")) {
                    System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
        .
.
.
.
.
```

I am able to connect and ready emails in local machine i.e Windows. But Not able to connect the same when deployed on linux. Is there any reason & solution for this..

Comment: Where do user and password come from? Perhaps you haven't configured your installation on Linux the same as windows.

Comment: The reason is quite clear from the error message. You need to configure the required credentials in your email server.

Comment: Ok.. the problem was the email host related keys defined as `user` and `password` in `application.properties` file for `spring boot` in `Linux` env were seem to be reserved. I changed them to `user_` and `password_`. But surprisingly they were not causing any trouble in `windows` env.